# CSS - Grid framework

Tags: css, sass

I have used both Foundation and Bootstrap, but I realised that the thing I only use it the grid. 
 
I haven't had any problems with their grids, and don't really have a preference yet. 
 
My question is, is it worth keep using them or is it better to use a framework that only has a grid system? 
 
I prefer SASS over LESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep using Bootstrap in case you ever want to borrow a bit of its functionality but don't want Bootstrap clashing with some other grid system's code.

If you don't want any of Bootstrap's extra styling muddling your design, [follow these instructions](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/651) to load only the grid from Bootstrap. Then, if you decide you need a quick dropdown navbar, just import the bits of Bootstrap you need.